# http proxy over ssh, not socks

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, socks-proxy, http-proxy

The question is simple, but the answer is not :

```
ssh -D 8080 user@host
```

or

```
ssh -gCNf -D 8080 user@host
```

or

```
wathever with -D #
```

I need a kind of proxy that i can use with http_proxy variable, in an embedded device that doesn't support SOCKS.

What should i do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ssh -D user@host:8080` ?

Comment: i've done it with ssh a while back.. vnc through ssh. but you could I suppose use squid(an http proxy) through ssh. can't recall how i did it though at the moment. it's not -D 'cos (as you know -and better than me) -D is SOCKS if I recall.

Comment: @ngen: No. `-D` specifies a port to open the tunnel on, not the port to connect to. (Even the *connection* port is specified as `-p port`, not `:port`, for compatibility reasons.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Method 1:** Use a HTTP proxy that supports using a SOCKS upstream, e.g. Polipo or Privoxy.

First establish a `-D` tunnel over SSH like always, then configure the HTTP proxy to use the SSH tunnel – example Polipo configuration:

```
proxyAddress = "::1"
proxyPort = 8118
socksParentProxy = "localhost:8080"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

Finally, point the app to Polipo using `http_proxy=localhost:8118`.

**Method 2:** Run your program inside the `torsocks` wrapper (or the older `tsocks`), which proxies all connections transparently. It was meant for use with Tor, but works with any SOCKS server, including `ssh -D`.

**Method 3:** Set up a HTTP proxy *on your server*, then use `ssh -L` to access it.

Comment: Privoxy is the best solution. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 24):

Every `-D` results into a SOCKS server. If your client can not handle SOCKS forget `-D`.

You must run a HTTP-Proxy on the remote host and forward with `-L`:

```
ssh -f -N -n -L8080:127.0.0.1:8080 host
```

Comment: For a proxy to run, I found "tinyproxy" super simple and already configured reasonably by default.  On Ubuntu/etc remote host, just "sudo apt-get install tinyproxy", and then forward to port 8888 as above: "ssh -L8888:127.0.0.1:8888"

Comment: "tinyproxy" worked for me as well.  I had it up and running in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue that want to use HTTP proxy through SSH. Because many applications only support HTTP proxy, and HTTP proxy is easy to be used in command line environment.

Although searched several pages but I can't find a direct(can be chained with Polipo,  Privoxy, or tsocks ) way to do this...

After a days' work, I finished a simple Golang version of HTTP proxy over SSH. Feel free to play with it: [mallory](https://github.com/justmao945/mallory).

Currently only support RSA key(located at $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa) and password authorisation.

`host` is the SSH server address, `port` is `22` if is not changed by your admin.
The server side is just our old friend `sshd` with zero configuration.

```
mallory -engine=ssh -remote=ssh://host:port
```

or with username `user`

```
mallory -engine=ssh -remote=ssh://user@host:port
```

or with username `user` and password `1234`

```
mallory -engine=ssh -remote=ssh://user:1234@host:port
```

After connected, a HTTP proxy will serve on localhost:1315.

Answer (score 6):

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:12345 user@host
```

This will open port 8080 on the local machine, and forward all data to port 12345 on localhost, as seen from the remote machine.

Comment: Don't forget, you also have to have an HTTP proxy running on the remote host.  Port forwarding by itself won't help.

Answer (score 2):

Run Privoxy at the remote host, then connect via SSH to Privoxy using the `-L` option:

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be
         forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.  This
         works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side,
         optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a con-
         nection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
         the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port
         hostport from the remote machine.
```

([manpage source](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1))

Answer (score 1):

You can also use corkscrew (GPL)

Add the following to your `.ssh/config`

```
Host=RemoteServerIP or Name
User=UserLoginName
Port=PortNumber
ProxCommand=/usr/bin/corkscrew Proxy.Adress PortNumber %h %p
```

Comment: corkscrew runs ssh over an http proxy, not the reverse that is asked for.

Answer (score 0):

More detailed instructions for using privoxy, all of this can be run as your own user.

This will create a http proxy at `127.0.0.1:17470` that terminates on remote-ssh-server.

1. Create a socks proxy at `127.0.0.1:17471` with ssh:

   ```bsh
   ssh -f -NT -M -S ~/.ssh/ssh_socket-named-foobar -D 127.0.0.1:17471 remote-ssh-server
   ```
2. Test the socks proxy at `127.0.0.1:17471` with curl:

   ```bsh
   curl --silent --proxy socks4a://127.0.0.1:17471 -4 https://checkip.amazonaws.com
   ```
3. Create privoxy config

   ```bsh
   cat > ~/.config/privoxy-foobar.conf <<EOF
   listen-address  127.0.0.1:17470
   forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:17471 .
   EOF
   ```
4. Start privoxy which creates an http proxy at `127.0.0.1:17470` which will pass through socks proxy at `127.0.0.1:17471`

   ```bsh
   privoxy --pidfile "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-/run/user/$(id -u)}/privoxy-foobar.pid" ~/.config/privoxy-foobar.conf
   ```
5. Test http proxy at `127.0.0.1:17470` with curl:

   ```bsh
   curl --silent --proxy http://127.0.0.1:17470 -4 https://checkip.amazonaws.com
   ```
6. Kill everything when you are done

   ```bsh
   ssh -S ~/.ssh/ssh_socket-named-foobar -O exit example.com # hostname is ignored, so yes it is fine to put example.com
   kill "$(cat "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-/run/user/$(id -u)}/privoxy-foobar.pid")"
   ```

Notes:

- You probably would want to change `foobar` in the commands to some name that makes sense to you, could run multiple proxies with different names like that.

Answer (score 0):

On the isolated system, get proxychains and tmux. and set the last line of /etc/proxychains.conf to tell it you have a socks5 proxy at localhost with port 8080.
Then also from the isolated system (and in tmux)

`ssh -D8080 you@systemwithinternet`

Leave it running, make a new shell in tmux with ctrl-b,c
Then run whatever that needs internet access with proxychains like so:

```
sudo proxychains apt update
```

You can even detach and leave it going with CTRL-b,d
Then you can break the ssh connection to the remote machine: it’ll keep going with the counter-connection still running in tmux.

Reattach later with `tmux a`  to see how it went.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to install polipo to create the HTTP proxy. Head over to the terminal and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install polipo
```

Once installed open the polipo configuration file: vim /etc/polipo/config and add the following lines:

```
socksParentProxy = “127.0.0.1:1337”
socksProxyType = socks5
proxyAddress = “::0”
proxyPort = 8123
```

Restart polipo:

```
sudo service polipo restart
```

Next set up your SOCKS proxy. If you’re already using it you don’t need to perform this step.

```
ssh -fN -D1337 user@server
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?