# Routing HTTP traffic over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, routing, http, tunnel

I need to access the URL `http://REMOTE:54000`. My network does not allow outgoing connections on port 54000. However I have SSH access to a host "TRUSTED", which does not have any such restrictions. Is it possible to route the traffic to REMOTE on port 54000 through ssh on TRUSTED.

All hosts run some version of ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a forwarding tunnel:

```
ssh -NL <localport>:REMOTE:54000 user@TRUSTED
```

then connect to `localhost:localport` to get to `remote:54000`. You'll need to figure out what `localport` you can use, or you can set it up as `80` and route all HTTP traffic through REMOTE that way (easiest way to get a HTTP proxy when you need it).

You can also install a local proxy as per: [http proxy over ssh, not socks](https://superuser.com/questions/280129/http-proxy-over-ssh-not-socks)